# create virtual host in Nginx docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I have a Laravel project that dockerized with Nginx, PHP, MySQL, and Redis. my os is ubuntu 18.04. I want to create a virtual host for example Laravel.dev  here is my docker-compose config for Nginx

```
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
      - ./:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - 8008:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - PHP
```

also I add 127.0.0.1 laravel.dev to my etc/hosts file

my Laravel project is at /var/www/html and this is the config file of Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.php;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
```

I won't paste all config here but it ok when open localhost:8008 and show the
laravel root.

how can make virtual host in Nginx container that point to /var/www/html/public; with Laravel.dev domain?

Comment: Replace `localhost`  in your nginx config with your domain. e.g `server_name laravel.dev`.